# How to ace the final home take exam?

Tags: professorship, email, exams, coursework, course-evaluation

I am an international grad student studying at a Canadian university. 
I have a home-take exam. It is the first time that I am taking this type of exam.

How should I prepare for this exam? Will it be a hard exam, since we are taking it home?

What are the policies for this exam? In other words, what are the do's and don't's?

Comment: These seem like questions you need to ask your professor or other students

Answer (score 3):

Your lecturer should've given you details about the policy for the exam. My understanding is that there're two possibilities:

The first is a simple take-home exam. You're free to take the exam whenever you want, wherever you want, but you must still conform to rules such as time to finish, no outside assistance, and so on. This kind of take-home exam operates by honor code. If you're unsure you'll be able to stop yourself from cheating, you can take it with other students and monitor each other.

The other is an open book exam. In this case no holds are barred (aside from outside assistance). You can use Google, look it up in textbooks, etc. Open book exams tend to be harder because simple questions will have easily Google-able answers and therefore mean nothing.

tl; dr: ask your professor for details.

Comment: English is my second language, I did not get what you mean here."This kind of take-home exam operates by honor code." what is honor code? could you pls explain this part as well" If you're unsure you'll be able to stop yourself from cheating, you can take it with other students and monitor each other."

Comment: @nikki2 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_honor_code - it's basically a belief that you will not cheat even though you can do it easily without fear of getting caught because you're an honest, trustworthy person. If you're afraid you will cheat anyway, then you can take the take-home exam with other students and stop each other from cheating.

Comment: If a student takes the take-home exam with other students. how he/she can prevent cheating? you mean by noticing each other that we should not talk to each  other?

Comment: @nikki2 cheating in a take-home exam could be, exam's supposed to last 2 hours but you work for 2.5 hours. Or you're not supposed to look at your textbook, but you do. If you take the exam alone, then succumbing to either temptation is very possible, but if you're with other students then you can stop each other from cheating.

Comment: In conclusion, so we need to abide by the honor code. since our professor trust us?

Comment: @nikki2 in conclusion, you need to ask your professor for details about the test. It could be your professor trusts you, or it could be an open book exam, or many other possibilities.